# ControlFX PropertySheet not showing anything

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I am using [ControlFX library](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/) in my project to generate forms dynamicly using PropertySheet.
Controllor class:

```
    public class Controllor implements Initializable
   {
    @FXML
    private PropertySheet sheet;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
    sheet = new PropertySheet(BeanPropertyUtils.getProperties(new BeanObj(someProperties)));
    sheet.setMode(PropertySheet.Mode.NAME);
    }
    }
```

My fxml file contains an AnchorPane and PropertySheet (just for testing).
The program runs with no errors but it shows an empty propertySheet control!
So , am I doing this right? Please any help would be appreciated !!
**EDIT:** I manage to get the application running by implementing the same code in the Start() method of the MainClass
I am still confused !! I can't figure it out...
**EDIT 2:** F5 solve everything to me

Comment: You were creating a second instance of `sheet`. With the `@FXML`  annotation, the `FXMLLoader`  created one.

Comment: I tried this approach but it gives me a nulPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were creating a second instance of `sheet`, but without being added to the scene graph.

With the `@FXML` annotation, the `FXMLLoader` created one that was the one added, but without content or elements.

This should work:

```
@FXML
private PropertySheet sheet;

public void initialize() {
    sheet.getItems().setAll(BeanPropertyUtils.getProperties(new BeanObj()));
    sheet.setMode(PropertySheet.Mode.NAME);
}
```

Comment: I am using eclipse and scene builder, for some reason fxml files were not (syncing) in eclipse!! that's why I kept getting error and empty scene !!! .  
F5 solved the problem !!! thanks anyway